# Spring Boot Actuator: can I change the logger level for entire package in one go?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot-actuator

In my Spring Boot application, I've enabled the Actuators, and I can see all my loggers at: `localhost:8080/loggers` like this:

```
"com.parent":{"configuredLevel":"INFO","effectiveLevel":"INFO"},
"com.parent.child":{"configuredLevel":"TRACE","effectiveLevel":"TRACE"}
[...]
```

Now I change the logging level by sending a request:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "DEBUG"}' http://localhost:8080/loggers/com.parent
```

Had the `configuredLevel` of `com.parent.child` not been set, changing the `com.parent`'s logging level would have changed `com.parent.child`'s  `effectiveLevel`.

Is there a way to override all children's logger level in a single request even though the `configuredLevel` has already been set?

I've tried using `*` as a wildcard symbol, but it didn't work. Is what I'm trying to do possible, or I have to reset the `configuredLevel` of all children separately?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to override all child logger levels where a child logger level has already been explicitly set.

Spring Boot's `LoggingEndpoint` delegates to `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.handleParentLevelChange()` and that method has a conditional block on `if(this.level == null) { }` so when the recursive call (which walks over all loggers) arrives at "com.parent.child" it will do nothing because "com.parent.child" already has an assigned level.

You can, of course, set a configuredLevel on a specific logger since that calls `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.setLevel()` and hence is not subject to the conditional block in `handleParentLevelChange()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this led me to a property that you might find useful.  Using curl, you can post the desired logging level as "" (zero length string) which has the effect of setting the configuredLevel to null.  This can be done for the child or parent in the hierarchy and then allows you dynamically set and unset from either the parent or the child class logging levels.